# Strange characters when passing string from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, string, variables

When the user presses the submit button from different forms, action pages execute their jobs. Before the end of those action pages I have put this lines:

```
$_SESSION['status']="inserted";
header("Location: storage.php");
```

or

```
$_SESSION['status']="removed";
header("Location: storage.php");
```

or

```
$_SESSION['status']="updated";
header("Location: storage.php");
```

The purpose of those lines is to save "globally" the success of the operation and then take the user to another page (`storage.php`).

In the `storage.php` page I want to show a specific message (depending on the operation) to inform the user that everything went fine (`<body onload = "statusMessage()">`).

Since `$_SESSION['status']` is a PHP variable and the message is displayed using Javascript I googled a way to pass variables form PHP to Javascript.

The following code is what I have done:

In `storage.php` I have put these lines:

```
<div id="data-status" style="display: none;">
   <?php
      echo $_SESSION['status']; // put as the div content
      $_SESSION['status']=""; // clear the variable
   ?>
</div>
```

with the purpose to save into an "invisible" `<div>` the value of my PHP variable.

Then I use DOM to access to that value:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
            function statusMessage() {
               var status = document.getElementById("data-status").textContent;               
               
                switch(status){
                    case "inserted":
                        alert("Data inserted into database");
                        break;
                    case "removed":
                        alert("Data removed from database");
                        break;
                    case "updated": 
                        alert("Data updated");
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert('Status code not known!');
                        break;
                }

            }
</script>
```

The problem is that always the default case is executed showing `"Status code not known!"`.

Trying to debug I wrote this code:

```
               var status = document.getElementById("data-status").textContent;
               var string = "inserted";
               console.log(string);
               console.log(typeof(string));
               console.log(string.length);
               console.log("--------------------");
               console.log(status);
               console.log(typeof(status));
               console.log(status.length);
```

and that's the output:

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkooE.png)

It seems that for some strange reason, special non printable characters are added to the `status` string. I don't know why and how to remove them.

Sorry for my long message, I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have whitespace around the value. Use `.textContent.trim()` to remove the surrounding spaces.

Comment: Also, on a processing note: PHP can generate _anything_, not just HTML, so instead of putting values in an invisible div, you can also have PHP generate the JS you need, with all the session values in it. I.e. don't inline bare script in the page, but load `<script src="session.js.php"></script>` and make PHP generate the JS response with the correct js headers.